# Make unavailable/undesirable dates disabled in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to make all the undesirable/meaningless dates in terms of my application context on my jquery ui datepicker calendar disabled to improve the user experiences but for some reason all of them are disabled.

I am using the jquery ui datepicker.

Any help will be appreciated. I have tried manually looping through each item in the array as well.

My Code:

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  console.log($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates));
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
  }
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekop9nwf/)**

Comment: The condition is just reversed, should be `if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {...`

Comment: @adeneo doesn't fix it

Comment: Doesn't it -> http://jsfiddle.net/ekop9nwf/2/

Comment: @adeneo whoops you are right.. i was checking the older dates lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reversed the condition, you want to return `true`, as in the days are selectable if they aren't in the array, and `false` if they are not selectable, i.e. they are in the array

```js
var unavailableDates = ["9-8-2017", "14-8-2017", "15-8-2017", "16-8-2017", "17-8-2017", "18-8-2017"];

function available(date) {
  var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
  }
}

$('#date').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: available
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" readonly="readonly" size="12" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: @user4756836 - because the dates aren't the same. You've suddenly started using `2017-08-04` while you're checking if the date is `04-08-2017`

Comment: Yea i just figured that... it was my main problem the whole time :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should check

`$.inArray(date, unavailableDates) === -1`

it'll means that `date` NOT IN `unavailableDates`

Secondly you should compare dates with `new Date().getTime()`, check jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ekop9nwf/3/

```
var unavailableDates = [new Date("9-5-2011").getTime(), new Date("14-5-2011").getTime(), new Date("15-5-2011").getTime()];

function available(date) {  
  if ($.inArray(date.getTime(), unavailableDates) === -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
 } else {
   return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
 }
}

$('#date').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: available
});
```